# Codeigniter: Installation problems with remote system and app folders on byethost

Tags: php, codeigniter, hosting

In the codeigniter installation guide  [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/) it says that for the best security the system and application folder should be set above web root. I kinda liked the idea so I gave it the shot.

In the byethost example it is in the same folder as the htdocs (I think)

I got the server path via the echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
So that mine is something like:
/home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/htdocs

So i tried putting the path in index.php as

```
 $application_folder = 'home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/application';
 $system_path = 'home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/system';
```

But it didn't work

```
  Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. 
  Please open the following file and correct this: index.php
```

Same with the application folder?

Can someone help me set this up properly?

EDIT:

Details:

Host php version:  5.3.14
Codeiniter: 2.1.3
Write premisions in root: rwxr-x--x

EDIT 2:

When I set

```
   $application_folder = 'home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/htdocs/application';
   $system_path = 'home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/htdocs/system';
```

it will work, meaning that it is probably the host who is not allowing this.

EDIT 3:

When I put

```
    $system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../system";
```

The page won't load and won't even display the error message.

Comment: Probably you forgot / in paths.. Actually you can use `dirname(__FILE__) . '/../system` and `dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application`

Answer (score 3):

Setting path for CodeIgniter system and application folders that lie in a directory above of webroot can be achieved with following:

1. Move `system` and `application` folder above your webroot.

   1.1 Some hosting providers do not allow this, so beware.
2. Open `index.php` and change:

   ```
   $system_folder = "system";
   ```

   to

   ```
   // if you are using pre-php5.3
   $system_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../system";
   // if you are using php5.3
   $system_folder = __DIR__ . "/../system";
   ```
3. depending on version of CodeIgniter.

   3.1 For pre 2.0:

   ```
   $application_folder = "application";
   ```

   3.2 For 2.0+

   ```
   $application_folder = '../application';
   ```

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I tried this but I could not get it to work on both localhost or on the byethost.

Comment: Strange.. should work. Can you do a `var_dump(realpath($system_folder))` after setting it like in answer?

Comment: I think it is because of the host, even though I can put the app and sys path to be: /home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/htdocs/application and it works fine, when I put /home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/application it won't work.

Comment: also check if your server can read from that folder. It should have at least `rw-r--r--` rights

Comment: When I  $system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../system"; It doesn't even display the error.

Comment: For the vrite premissions it is rwxr-x--x

Comment: you can try setting just `$system_path = "../system";`. Probably you need to have to `chmod o+r ../system`

Comment: The var_dump(): string(45) "/home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username/htdocs"

Comment: Yes, it seems like your hosting provider restricts php to use only webroot. Once last check to be sure: `var_dump(__DIR__) . '/../'` should return `"/home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_username"`

Comment: `var_dump(__DIR__) . '/../';` For local host it returns the value on the provider it returns nothing.

Comment: Oh, sorry. seem i've missed part of the code. Should be `var_dump(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));`

Comment: For `var_dump(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'));` it returns (bool) false, for `var_dump(realpath(__DIR__));` it returns string(45) "/home/vol8/byethost17.com/my_site/htdocs"

Comment: then your server configuration forbids PHP to traverse above webroot. Or you are have wrong access rules